# some confusion in bounded variation.?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f(x) =  \tan (\frac{x}{2}) $ is bounded variation on $( -\pi /2 , \pi/2)$ ?

I think yes    because its derivative is bounded

Is its true ?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, it is true.